# How can i login after saving data into my server?

Tags: php, mysql

I'm learning php and mysql and i'm making fake login site. -for learning purpose-

```
    <?php
$id = $_POST[mb_id];
$password = $_POST[mb_password];
// Create connection
 $conn = mysqli_connect(localhost, u982680175_root, temp, u982680175_test);
 // Check connection
 if (!$conn) {
     die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$sql = "INSERT INTO student (id, password)
 values ('$id', '$password')";

if (mysqli_query($conn, $sql)) {
    header("Location: http://www.dtg.hs.kr/");
exit();

} else {
    echo "Error: " . $sql . "<br>" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

i sucess saving data in to my server and redirected to realhomepage. but i want to redirect to **logined** real site after saving database. 
how can i call real php and give data?
this is the real login page: http://www.dtg.hs.kr/sys/bbs/login.php

Comment: Simply change the URL in `Location: http://www.dtg.hs.kr/` to whatever you want to be redirected to.

Comment: do you mean you want the user to be automatically logged in after registration completed? **note** you may want to hide database info username/pass if this info is real.

Comment: yes, and the username/password is not real.

Comment: @user3801693 you will need to have your files hosted on the real site, to be able to add a session record for that user, once registration is completed. but having your files on another host, will not work, as this session is on ur host and will not be set at the real host session

Answer (score 0):

Short answer...

After the data from the user being created is inserted into the database you will need to have the script create some sort of $_SESSION[] variable that uniquely identifies the user.

Here is the PHP documentation related to SESSIONs http://php.net/manual/en/book.session.php

When the redirect occurs there will be a check to see if the $_SESSION variable is set or not. If the $_SESSION variable is set, then do a check to see if the $_SESSION variable is valid.

In then you will be able to show different data based on the validated $_SESSION or if no $_SESSION is set.

Hope this helps!